# SoundCloud: callback.html popup doesn't close

Tags: authentication, soundcloud

### I've registered my SoundCloud app.

I'm trying to implement the SoundCloud JS example code with the "callback.html" API
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#authentication http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/recording.html

When I upload a recording, I get the authorization-login popup.
After I login, the popup says "This popup should auto close..."
But the **popup doesn't close.**
And the recording isn't uploaded.

I'm positive SC.initialize has my correct "clientID" and is referencing "callback.html" correctly from my directory.
Am I missing something?  maybe "client secret"?

```
SC.initialize({
        client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        redirect_uri: "http://www.example.com/callback.html"
      });
```

One time (fluke) instead of the normal pop msg "This should close", the message said "502 Bad Gateway".  But I havent been able to reproduce this msg.

Comment: Have you tried to open the developer tools on the popup window to see the console output? (e.g. in Chrome press `Ctrl+Shift+I`). I can reproduce your issue with my test page being on HTTP and my callback page on HTTPS. The output console says `... SecurityError ... Protocols must match.`

Comment: If that's your case, you can bypass this error (for test purposes) by restarting Chrome with the option `--disable-web-security`.

Comment: I would really love an answer to this question - I can't even get the basic example in their API docs working. The popup just hangs. I see no errors on the popup console, so I have no idea what's going on. My credentials (clientId, redirectUri etc.) are all configured correctly, yet no luck.

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud's sample code is broken.

This is from SoundCloud's `callback.html`

```
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

This is how I got it to work:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

SoundCloud's `connectCallback` uses `this.location` to collect the OAuth access token. If you set the timeout on `window.opener`, inside `connectCallback` `this` will refer to your app's `window` and the location will be your main page. Whereas setting it on `window` will bind `this` to the callback popup window, and `this.location` will contain the access token in the query arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, and found the solution, if you change your `callback.html` to below two options, it will work -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.opener.SC.connectCallback.call(this);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback)">
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>
```